# Method not found: '!!0[] System.Array.Empty()'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I created a new app with VS 2015 RC and the MVC template and without modifying any line of code I have this error:

```
Method not found: '!!0[] System.Array.Empty()'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: '!!0[] System.Array.Empty()'.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[MissingMethodException: Method not found: '!!0[] System.Array.Empty()'.]
   SAASApp.BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles) in C:\Proyectos\SAASApp\SAASApp\App_Start\BundleConfig.cs:29
   SAASApp.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in C:\Proyectos\SAASApp\SAASApp\Global.asax.cs:18

[HttpException (0x80004005): Method not found: '!!0[] System.Array.Empty()'.]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +483
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +118
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +176
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +350
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +305

[HttpException (0x80004005): Method not found: '!!0[] System.Array.Empty()'.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +661
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +96
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +189
```

First time it happens to me, so I am stuck at the moment

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC 5 Bundle Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29020614/mvc-5-bundle-error)

Answer (score 249, accepted):

I had this situation on the production server while on development machine everything was OK.

Installing .NET Framework 4.6 on the target machine has fixed the problem.

Comment: PC LOAD LETTER!

Comment: Thank you.
Most likely what is happening is that:
- The code is compiling against .NET 4.6, where the reference assemblies include Array.Empty<T>().
- The Roslyn compiler sees that Array.Empty<T> is available and so uses it when generating the empty array needed for the params.
- The compiled app is trying to run on .NET 4.5 where Array.Empty doesn’t exit.

Comment: Our Windows 2008R2 Server had to restart once after installation.

Comment: When looking for answer found this thread which gives some more background why this is happens https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4889

Comment: I installed .net461 but still had the same error. Installing net472 did the trick for me

Answer (score 28):

Sorry for being late to the party, but in case someone else gets this problem via a TeamCity build, I can describe what we had to do.

.NET 4.6 was installed on our build server (but not on the application server), and the RunnerType was Visual Studio (sln) and the Visual Studio option was set to 2015.

This forced the build to use 4.6, and I needed to change the Visual Studio option to 2013 to force the build to use 4.5.2

Comment: A good colleague of mine pointed out to me that you can build with Visual Studio 2015 if your build agent has the requirement DotNetFrameworkTargetingPack4.5.2_Path

TeamCity will then build the solution towards 4.5.2, even if 4.6 is installed

Comment: I resolved this issue by using the 4.5.2 dev pack as @gman suggested. In situations where you don't want to have 4.6 installed, this seems like a better solution.

Comment: Asking after many years, this is for you @Dougc. I am in a similar situation, i don't want 4.6 installed and i have 4.5.2 installed. Still i get this issue. What is it that gman suggested??

Comment: @singsuyash, in the project configuration, go to Agent Requirements. There you click add new requirement. Type DotNetFrameworkTargetingPack4.5.2_Path in the parameter name and set condition to exist.

Answer (score 12):

**Just For others facing this situation:**

if you look in the web.config file you will realize that in `<compilation>` tag you have the value `targetFramework` set to a version below 4.6. but in fact , at build time you published your application via .NET FrameWork 4.6 or above (Corresponds to ASP.NET MVC 4.6 and above).

So if you change the value of `targetFramework` to 4.6 the error will change shape into :

> The 'targetFramework' attribute currently references a version that is later than the installed version of the .NET Framework.

this is the real error and you will get rid of it by installing appropriate Version of .Net FrameWork in production environment of your Web App.

Comment: However, after you do this, and depending on the project template selected when the application was created, if you have the insight and codeDom applications installed, you may have to uninstall them as I did. I received an array error which traced back to roslyn and Microsoft Application Insight.

Answer (score 5):

**Updating the .NET Framework to its latest (4.7.2) resolved the issue.**
Thanks to @Andrey Kovalenko for solution.

But should not the error be like,

[image]

I am not sure telling each customer about updating their .NET Framework is applicable. I had this issue especially at **Windows Embedded OS** installed system, only at production environment.

Is there any other way to overcome the behavior, from our code base itself.?

Comment: Targeting older **.NET Framework (4.0 Client Profile)** for my project and all DLL projects also worked. :)

Answer (score 2):

I try these solution without success.

The solution for me was go to the application pool, turn to 2.0, execute the site on browser, see the error (because the version is wrong) and turn back to 4.0 and "voilà", I got it, the website open.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it too late but I got the same problem and fixed as below. 
I use Visual Studio 2015 ,the configuration **compilation** on web.config point to .NET FrameWork 4.6 by default. I could not just edit only on the web.config file.  If you can not install .NET FrameWork 4.6 on server and your application don't use it.

1. Go to menu Debug > [Project Name] Properties > Application .
2. choose the .NET Framework 4.5 (or any which server support and compatible your application) from Target Framwork dropdown list.
3. Rebuild again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a corrupt .NET installation on my Windows Server 2012 R2. I had to install a more recent version of .NET (v4.7.1) and the site is working now.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I don't have access to the IIS itself and I was having this problem when I was using a single method which doesn't have anything special only things from .net 2.

The solution: I've Extracted that method and created a Class Library with .net 2.0 and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have downgraded 4.6.x to 4.5.2 and it worked fine.