# ASP.NET MVC 4 works fine locally but gives System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: '!!0[] System.Array.Empty()'. when published

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have published the project that is working fine locally and I'm getting an error that I actually haven't seen till now:

> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: '!!0[] System.Array.Empty()'.

This is the stack trace:

> [MissingMethodException: Method not found: '!!0[] System.Array.Empty()'.]
>      Mozaede_v3.BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles) in C:\Users\Ashkan\OneDrive\Projects\Mozaede-v3\Mozaede-v3\App_Start\BundleConfig.cs:30
>      Mozaede_v3.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in C:\Users\Ashkan\OneDrive\Projects\Mozaede-v3\Mozaede-v3\Global.asax.cs:18
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Method not found: '!!0[] System.Array.Empty()'.]
>      System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +9916673
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +118
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
>      System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
>      System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Method not found: '!!0[] System.Array.Empty()'.]
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9930568
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254

My real problem is that, what is this exception? 
why does it work perfectly locally?

Comment: This link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31253747/method-not-found-0-system-array-empty-asapp-bundleconfig-registerbundl suggests it might be a framework issue.

Comment: Is your application targeting .NET 4.6.1 framework?

Comment: If you are targeting .net 4.6.1 or above, see if adding Microsoft.Net.Compilers 1.3.2 as a dependency into your project resolves your issue. With this your application will have everything required to build as .NET 4.6.1 app. More details please visit https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers/

Comment: Yes changing the target .net framework versio to 4.5.1 solved the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Method not found: '!!0\[\] System.Array.Empty()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31253747/method-not-found-0-system-array-empty)