# Method not found: '!! 0 [] System.Array.Empty ()'

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I have IIS 8.5 version. And my web api project framework is .Net 4.6 . I publish the web api and it is work on local iis express or my computer(windows 8.1) iis. But when I publish the api on windows server r2 2012 iis and when I click browse, I get below error.

Note: server iis version is same as my computer version.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Method not found: '!! 0 [] System.Array.Empty ()'.
>
> Explanation: An unhandled exception occurred while executing the current web request. Please review the stack trace to find out more about the error and where it originates in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: '!! 0 [] System.Array.Empty ()'.

[image]

Comment: check if the server has installed .net 4.6. Even that the dll is compiled, ASP.NET will be precompiled form the IIS. If you don't have .net 4.6 on the server, this should be the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Method not found: '!!0\[\] System.Array.Empty()'. ASApp.BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles) inBundleConfig.cs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31253747/method-not-found-0-system-array-empty-asapp-bundleconfig-registerbundl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved problem as below:

1. Download and install windows updates.
2. After , install .net 4.6.2

Answer (score 4):

Check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

On the first request the IIS will try to precompile the code files and the webpages. If you are using Array.Empty in (.aspx or a .cs file in the App_Code directory .. etc) and there is no .net 4.6 installed on the server, the exception will be raised.

Comment: thanks for answer ,  I am loading essential updates to install .net 4.6 now.  Then probably problem will be fixed